# component is not getting loaded in yii2 basic

Tags: yii2, yii-components

I am using yii2 basic template. I am trying create RBAC DB using database migration in yii2, I have created few tables successfully and while I am creating RBAC tables I have got different function as show below:

```
protected function getAuthManager()
{
    $authManager = Yii::$app->getAuthManager();
    if (!$authManager instanceof DbManager) {
        throw new InvalidConfigException('You should configure "authManager" component to use database before executing this migration.');
    }
    return $authManager;
}
```

This function is not returning authManager even though I have added this

```
'authManager'=>[
    'class'=>'yii\rbac\DbManager',
],`
```

in console.php

first few lines of error is:

```
Exception: You should configure "authManager" component to use database before executing this migration. (C:\xampp\htdocs\PMTool\migrations\m150820_064854_rbac.php:13)
 C:\xampp\htdocs\PMTool\migrations\m150820_064854_rbac.php(20): m150820_064854_rbac->getAuthManager()
```

code of console.php

```
`<?php

Yii::setAlias('@tests', dirname(__DIR__) . '/tests');

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');
$db = require(__DIR__ . '/db.php');

return [
'id' => 'basic-console',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
'bootstrap' => ['log', 'gii'],
'controllerNamespace' => 'app\commands',
'modules' => [
    'gii' => 'yii\gii\Module',
],
'components' => [
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
    ],
    'log' => [
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'db' => $db,
    'authManager'=>[
        'class'=>'yii\rbac\DbManager',
    ],
],
'params' => $params,
];
```

Comment: Just to be sure: Did you add it under `"components"`? Impossible to see here. (although I suspect `Yii` won't start if you added it somewhere else)

Comment: `'authManager'=>[
    'class'=>'yii\rbac\DbManager',
],`  add in `web.php` file , section of `componets` array.

Comment: yes i have added it under components @Blizz

Comment: i have added it in web.php and console.php but actually I am working on migrations in console, So I think adding this in web.php will not have an impact on resolving this issue.@gamitg

Comment: @akhil you are right about the `web.php` remark not solving anything

Comment: show your console.php complete code please

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue.By including DbManager in migrations class as below

`use yii\rbac\DbManager;`

Comment: Hmm, that does not really seem like a correct solution. You should not have to modify Yii's migrations (or is it one of your own?)

Comment: migrations are my own. I have coded them. Is there any other way without including DbManager

Comment: Okay, I think I get it now, see if my answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, with your answer I get it: You probably copied the `class` of the [original RBAC migration script](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/rbac/migrations/m140506_102106_rbac_init.php), but forgot to include the `use` lines on the top of the file, is that possible?

Since the `use` is missing it is not known what `DbManager` actually means, so  `getAuthManager()` checks against an unknown class and the condition fails. 
This also explains why the problem was solved by you adding the `use yii\rbac\DbManager`.

That being said, the correct way to run the framework migrations is by simply using the `migrationPath` option:

```
./yii migrate --migrationPath=vendor/yiisoft/yii2/rbac/migrations
```

I would say, try that and it would cause you a whole lot less problems :)

Comment: Hi Blizz. Can i directly copy this code "./yii migrate --migrationPath=vendor/yiisoft/yii2/rbac/migrations" to run in my terminal. Or, i've to change any code like migrationPath

Comment: No you should be able to just use it like that, its basic functionality