# Configuring authManager using DbManager in yii2-app-base

Tags: php, yii2, rbac, yii2-basic-app

I'm going through [Security-Authorization Tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html) to configure authManager using DbManager.

After declaring the below code in **web.php**

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
      'showScriptName' => false,
      'enablePrettyUrl' => true
    ], 
    'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
        ],
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'tYXyeisqgn9Qn_baaI6JRV4a6NY54nrq',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
        'viewPath' => '@backend/mail',
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'port' => '8080',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
                        ],
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    ];
}

return $config;
```

And, this code in **console.php**

```
    <?php

Yii::setAlias('@tests', dirname(__DIR__) . '/tests');

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');
$db = require(__DIR__ . '/db.php');

return [
    'id' => 'basic-console',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log', 'gii'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'app\commands',
    'modules' => [
        'gii' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    ],
    'components' => [
    'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => $db,
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

**config/db.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=danishYii',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

I typed `./yii migrate --migrationPath=vendor/yiisoft/yii2/rbac/migrations`
in my terminal. This command i got from [Component is not getting loaded -Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32112290/component-is-not-gettting-loaded-in-yii2-basic/32115605?noredirect=1#comment53565797_32115605)

I got this error in my terminal

> Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'

[image]

I'm very new to Yii. So please don't mind if this is a silly question.
Please help me to rectify this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if in your

```
console/config/main.php
```

you have a proper configuration for db access like this sample for yii2-app-advanced template

```
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=your_hostname;dbname=your_dbname',
        'username' => 'your_username',
        'password' => 'your_password',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'enableSchemaCache' => true,            
    ],
```

for basic template

be sure you have in basic/console/config.php a reference to db in component secion like this

```
return [
     .......
    'components' => [
         ......
    'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
    ],
      ......
];
```

and then in basci/config/db.php a properly  db config

```
    return [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=your_hostname;dbname=your_dbname',
        'username' => 'your_username',
        'password' => 'your_password',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ];
```

Comment: Hi Mr Scais. I think this configuration is for yii2-app-advanced. I'm having config/db.php. I'm editing my question. Please have a look .

Comment: Yeah. Mr @Scais. I'm having 'db' => $db, in console.php

Comment: Is not right Hi have update the answer check if in your console.php ypu have a proper reference to db.php

Comment: check again you need       `  'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),`

Comment: i edited my question with full code of web.php and console.php Mr Scais.

Comment: In your console.php you have 'db'=> $db. You should change this entry like i posted in my answer (in my comment are not showed the underscore use the answer samplet 'db'=> replace.....)

Comment: But your basic application work  with db you can access / register a user? (not console command like Yii migrate, but app basic)

Comment: Yeah. I'm successfully registering User and login also. But, after this i got to knew about security authorization, then i headed towards it.